# Prevent document from jumping after refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use https://github.com/dmsl/academic-responsive-template to design a website but it has this issue where on refresh, the content jumps down. If I refresh, the content below the navigation bar visibly starts out higher, and then jumps down after a bit to its final position. How can I stop this behaviour and start out with the final position instead of this jump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a height of 28px to this element

[screenshot about at what position in bio.html to apply height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReAOo.png)